# How do you 'rotate' a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, analytic-geometry

I have a polynomial equation:

$$y=(-5 \times 10^{-6} \times x^3)+(0.0004 \times x^2)+(0.0582 \times x)-0.4397$$

Is it possible to "rotate" this polynomial curve (maintaining the shape) around the point (10, 0.1773) so that it follows the gradient of the straight line:

$$y=(0.0222 \times x)+0.41797$$

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you want to move the X axis or something?

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is a new rotated coordinates $(x', y')$, and your polynomial curve has the same form
$$y' = f(x') = -5\times 10^{-6}(x')^3 + 0.0004(x')^2 + 0.0582 x'-0.4397$$

Also, each point in $(x', y')$ is rotated from the original coordinates by an angle $\theta$ (to be obtained from your straight line):

$$\pmatrix{x'-10\\y'-0.1773} = 
\pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos \theta}
\pmatrix{x-10\\y-0.1773}$$

where $\tan \theta = 0.02222$.

Substitute these $x'$ and $y'$, in terms of $x$ and $y$, into the first equation.

Comment: The "rotation" in the original question also contains a translation, if $x=0$ then $y=0.41..$.

Comment: I read that the curve should only follow the gradient of that straight line; can @TDJ92 confirm if translation is required?

Comment: In the question I meant for the curve to be rotated round a point (10, 0.1773), and then for the curve to follow the gradient of the straight line (so if you plotted them on top of each other, the polynomial would 'follow' the straight line. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: First, translate -- $x'=x-10$ and $y'=y-.1773$ -- then do the rotation, then reverse the translation.

Comment: Just a note: this transformation will rotate the graph clockwise through the angle $\theta.$